# Numbering Based on Condition(s)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm trying to create auto numbering for Agents that are currently present and has numbers including zeroes 0 in 3rd or 4th column(zero meaning they don't get any stats but they are present)

Agents who has TEXT Value in the 3rd or 4th column are those who are not present (Ex: A = Absent, SL = Sick Leave, VL = Vacation Leave). Meaning, they should not be counted, therefore their value on 1st column should be blank, and therefore this should not stop the auto numbering for the rest of the agents below and should continue the count in sequence.

[image]

Can anyone help create formula that would fill the numbers on the 1st column automatically for those agents that are present and has value including 0 on column 3 or 4 (stats 1 or stats 2)?

To give more idea, I'm trying to show the current total number of agents who are currently present in this situation and will count their stats, and exclude all other agents who are not present and should not be counted.

Thank you!

Comment: What is your excel version? what happens if Stat1 as a letter and Stat2 has a number for a given agent?

Comment: @david leal - Currently using Office 365. Still the same, Should still not be numbered because we will recognize the agent as Absent, but good question, it can actually happen sometime, some agent can be absent but can have a stat, if that were to happen my solution would be is just a simple sum function on the total below (last row)

Thank you

Comment: In cell `A3`, a basic not spilling formula would be `=IF(ISNUMBER(C3*D3),MAX(A$2:A2)+1,0)` with the condition of a string in cell `A2`. Let me know if you need a spilling formula.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I got it.

This is the formula that I made

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(D2:BE2,"*",$D$1:$BE$1,TODAY())>0,"",MAX(A1:A$4)+1)
```

Countif criteria 1 = if the cell contains a letter and is counted > 0 then it will return blank, otherwise it will start the count using max function. The countif criteria 2 will will return the correct value according to the date today since the excel sheet has several data daily.

Answer (score 4):

### Sequence Two Numeric Columns

**Single Cell**

- In cell `A3`, a basic not spilling formula would be...

  ```
  =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(C3),ISNUMBER(D3)),MAX(A$2:A2)+1,"")
  ```

  ... with the condition of a string in cell `A2`.
- Without any conditions, you could try an improved version, similar to one of David Leal's suggestions:

  ```
  =IF(AND(ISNUMBER(C3),ISNUMBER(D3)),
      SUM(ISNUMBER(C$3:C3)*ISNUMBER(D$3:D3)),"")
  ```

**Spill**

- In cell `A3` you could use the following:

  ```
  =LET(Data1,C3:C13,Data2,D3:D13,
      Data,ISNUMBER(Data1)*ISNUMBER(Data2),
  IFERROR(SCAN(0,Data,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))/Data,""))
  ```

  - Line1: the inputs ('constants'), the same-sized single-column ranges
  - Line2: the zeros and ones, where the ones present the data of interest
  - Line3: the formula to replace the ones with the sequence and the zeros (errors due to division by zero) with an empty string
- Converted to a `LAMBDA`, it could look like the following:

  ```
  =LAMBDA(Data1,Data2,LET(
      Data,ISNUMBER(Data1)*ISNUMBER(Data2),
  IFERROR(SCAN(0,Data,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))/Data,"")))(C3:C13,D3:D13)
  ```
- Since it's such a long formula, you could create your own `Lambda` function by using this part...

  ```
  =LAMBDA(Data1,Data2,LET(
      Data,ISNUMBER(Data1)*ISNUMBER(Data2),
  IFERROR(SCAN(0,Data,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))/Data,"")))
  ```

  ... to define a name, e.g. `SeqNumeric`, when in the same cell, you could use
  it simply with...

  ```
  =SeqNumeric(C3:C13,D3:D13)
  ```

  ... instead.
- Now you can use the function like any other Excel function anywhere in the workbook.

[image]

**The Path**

```
F3  =ISNUMBER(C3:C13)*ISNUMBER(D3:D13) - multiply: zeros-no, ones-yes
G3  =SCAN(0,F3#,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b)) - use the 'LAMBDA' helper function 'SCAN'
H3  =G3#/F3# - divide the 'scan' result by the zeros and ones
I3  =IFERROR(H3#,"") - convert the '#DIV/0!' errors to empty strings
```

The translation of the `SCAN` part could be something like the following:

- Set the initial result `a` to `0`.
- Create a new array of the size of the initial array in `F3#`.
- Loop through each element of the initial array, write its value to `b`, and replace `a` with the sum of `a+b`.
- Write (the accumulated) `a` to the current element of the new array and repeat for the remaining elements of either array.
- Return the new array.

Combine all of it in a `LET`.

```
J3  =LET(Data1,C3:C13,Data2,D3:D13,
        Data,ISNUMBER(Data1)*ISNUMBER(Data2),
    IFERROR(SCAN(0,Data,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))/Data,""))
```

Convert to `LAMBDA`.

```
K3  =LAMBDA(Data1,Data2,LET(
        Data,ISNUMBER(Data1)*ISNUMBER(Data2),
    IFERROR(SCAN(0,Data,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))/Data,"")))(C3:C13,D3:D13)
```

Copy the first part of the `LAMBDA` (note how it results in a `#CALC!` error since no parameters are supplied)...

```
L3  =LAMBDA(Data1,Data2,LET(
        Data,ISNUMBER(Data1)*ISNUMBER(Data2),
    IFERROR(SCAN(0,Data,LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))/Data,"")))
```

... and select `Formulas -> Name Manager -> New` to create your own function and finally use it with the following:

```
A3   =SeqNumeric(C3:C13,D3:D13)
```

Comment: Great idea, to divide by zero to get the empty. I was trying to use `SCAN` but I couldn't deal with the zero case which breaks the accumulation.

Comment: @DavidLeal First of all, thanks for taking the time to have a look. Secondly, thanks for recognizing the centerpiece of my solution, although I wouldn't expect anything less from you. I overdid it with this post (still finding typos, hopefully, there are no remaining serious errors) so I haven't had time to study yours. I definitely will as I hope to do with your recent posts in relation to the new functions. It is quite easy although time-consuming to dissect the solutions. I'm sure it will pay off in the end. Thanks once more for your contribution from which I have learned quite a lot.

Comment: thanks @VBasic2008 for your comment, just a minor suggestion you can reduce more your solution removing one `ISNUMBER`, for example: `=LET(Data1, B3:B13, Data2, C3:C13, Data, ISNUMBER(Data1*Data2), IFERROR(SCAN(0,Data, LAMBDA(a, b,a+b))/Data, ""))` you can multiply `Data1` and `Data2`, and then to invoke `ISNUMBER`. Excel does the cast from boolean to `0`,`1`inside the `LAMBDA`. I tested it. Regards

Comment: @DavidLeal The issue is also found in my suggested single-cell formulas. The result of the expression `=ISNUMBER(A1)`, when cell `A1` is empty, is correctly `FALSE`. Unfortunately, the expression `=ISNUMBER(A1*B1)` will result in `TRUE` whether cell `B1` is empty or it contains a number, a behavior I don't want (OP hopefully neither) i.e. I would get `1` (or `TRUE`) for rows `5` and `7`. It behaves similarly to the `IsNumeric` function in VBA, e.g. `IsNumeric(Range("A1").Value)` will be `True` if cell `A1` is empty (use `VarType(Range("A1").Value) = vbDouble` to get `False` for an empty cell).

Comment: @VBasic2008 true, the OP requested that, but the sample doesn't provide such scenario, that is why it works for this sample Good point!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following in cell `A1`:

```
=LET(B, B2:B12, C, C2:C12, f, 1*ISNUMBER(B*C),seq, SEQUENCE(ROWS(B)),
  MAP(seq, LAMBDA(s, IF(INDEX(f,s)=0, "",SUM(FILTER(f, (seq<=s),0))))))
```

Here is the output:
[image: excel output]

A non-array version, expanding down the formula would be:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(B2*C2), SUM(1*ISNUMBER(B$2:B2*C$2:C2)),"")
```

For the array version, it counts only if both columns **Stat1** and **Stat2** are numeric. The name `f`, has a value of `1` if the condition is `TRUE`, otherwise is `0`. The `MAP` does the count if the index position of the `f` array is not zero, otherwise returns an empty string.

Comment: Hi, this actually works thank you so much! But is there a simpler version of this? Because I am adding several conditions after this. I appreciate this so much already anyway. Thank you!

Comment: @Harvey I simplified the array version and provided also the non-array version, you need to expand it down. I prefer always arrays version because it requires less effort to maintain, but it is a matter of preference. I guess this version fits your need. Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: I will also try this one to add this to my learnings! Thanks so much sir!